# How to configure IP address form France in Crawlera?

Tags: selenium, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler, scrapinghub

I use [Crawlera](http://crawlera.com/) in my Scrapy-Selenium Crawler.

but I need to use just the IP from **France**.

how can configure my crawlera to do this.

```
   custom_settings = {
        'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {'scrapy_crawlera.CrawleraMiddleware': 600},
        'CRAWLERA_ENABLED' : True,
        'CRAWLERA_APIKEY' : //my appikey,
        'DOWNLOAD_DELAY' : 0,
        'COOKIES_ENABLED' : True,
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to go to your Crawlera dashboard on http://app.scrapinghub.com and create a separate user, setting 'fr' as the region. Then, you use the new API key in your spiders.